# Showing 10 recent (same month/year?) items from a category (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, list, categories

I'd like to display **10 recent posts** (probably from the current month or year) from the "**featured**" category in **random** order, i.e, rotate posts on each refresh/pageload.

I'd like to show small thumbnails (the same image(s) used in the posts just resized to fit) on left, and excerpt on right. So the formatting would look like:

```
[#1 Post Title]
[80x80 thumbnail] [excerpt, limit to x chars]

[#2 Post Title]
[80x80 thumbnail] [excerpt, limit to x chars]

[#3 Post Title]
[80x80 thumbnail] [excerpt, limit to x chars]

... upto 10 posts
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just what I wanted: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thumbnail-for-excerpts/

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

Many plugins do random [WordPress › WordPress Plugins >> Search 
"Random Posts"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=random+posts). If they don't also do thumbnails, shouldn't be to hard to add a custom field to the query for the thumbnail.